# Improving Squat Power at Parallel

Tags: squats

In my squat, I find that I can get to depth, push up about an inch, and clear the squat another inch above that really easily. However, there's a point just above parallel where I struggle the most.

I filmed myself for the first time yesterday when I did 161 kg 1RM. I was constantly pushing above parallel for 3-4 seconds until I raised about 1-2 inches and could clear the remaining distance. There is an order of magnitude between the speed before and after that sticking point.

This is the weak point of my squat and I'm wondering if there is any accessory work I can do to strengthen that point or if there are any specific technique points I should be watching for. Tips and suggestions would be appreciated as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the good thing about doing a 1RM is that you find out stuff like this. Without seeing the video it's a little hard to know for sure.

Juggernaut Training Systems has a series of videos addressing weak points, which helped me personally. I had what I consider to be the same issue as you, however, it's always possible it could be caused by something different. My particular issue is that I have a relatively weak back. Which is outlined here:

- [Addressing Weak Points | Squat | Weak Back](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKQWs-GJZa4)

It might be worth watching these other two videos to see if they resonate with you more:

- [Addressing Weak Points | Squat | Out of the Hole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-nm8ry_C9Q)
- [Addressing Weak Points | Squat | Weak Legs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H61P_PXUs6k)

As a side note, I would make sure you're breathing and bracing properly. I'm sure you're aware of the Valsalva maneuver but it's always good to bring it up. It's always going to be beneficial to make sure to remain tight for the full squat duration.

Comment: Your second linked video, "Squat | Out of the Hole", is *exactly* what I am trying to describe. Down to depth and then pushing against a wall at parallel.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider trying some box squats. It can help you to focus your technique at this point of the lift, making sure that you're really bracing your core, 
 pushing your knees out and driving the hips forward. By adjusting the box height you can work on the exact stage of the lift that you're struggling with. There are plenty of [good articles](https://www.westside-barbell.com/blogs/2005-articles/box-squatting-benefits) on box squatting.

Some people also recommend good mornings to build posterior chain strength, although I would advise going easy with the weight and being mighty careful with the technique if you try these.